# how to re-enable default after doing event.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, events

I know this exact question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551389/how-to-enable-default-after-event-preventdefault), but the answer didn't work for what I needed to do so I figured I'd give some example code and explain a bit...

```
$(document).keypress(
    function (event) {
        // Pressing Up or Right: Advance to next video
        if (event.keyCode == 40 || event.keyCode == 39) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(".current").next().click();
        }
        // Pressing Down or Left: Back to previous video
        else if (event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 37) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(".current").prev().click();
        }
     }
 );
```

It basically disables the arrow keys to use them for something else, but doing:

```
$(document).keypress(function () { });
```

doesn't enable the default function again... I need it to scroll the page without having to create a scroll function for it...

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: right... sry I wrapped the "here" in an a tag but forgot to include the link. I've done so now, thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: LOL, you know, when I read it I *thought* the phrasing looked like it was begging for a link...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reenable event.preventDefault?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164132/how-to-reenable-event-preventdefault)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the right way to handle it.

A better way to approach this problem would be to put some kind of check inside your document.keypress instructions.. like..

```
var enableKeys = false;

$(document).keypress(
    function (event) {
        // Pressing Up or Right: Advance to next video
        if (event.keyCode == 40 || event.keyCode == 39 && enableKeys) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $(".current").next().click();
        }
        // Pressing Down or Left: Back to previous video
        else if (event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 37 && enableKeys) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(".current").prev().click();
        }
     }
 );
```

Then control the enablekeys wherever you feel necessary, either with a hover, or something along those lines.

Comment: +1 I am not sure if this is "a better way", but it is definitely a viable alternative if, for whatever reason, [T.J. Crowder's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608714/how-to-re-enable-default-after-doing-event-preventdefault/2608740#2608740) is unusable in some application.

Comment: Worked right away, guess it helped that it matched up exactly to my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Adding a new handler doesn't replace the previous one, it adds a new one. You may be looking for [`jQuery#unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) if you're trying to remove the previous handler, but if you're going to be turning this on and off a lot, you probably would be better off with a flag telling you whether to prevent the default or not in your existing handler.

Adding, and later removing, a handler looks like this:

```
function keypressHandler() { /* ... */};

$('#thingy').keypress(keypressHandler);

// ...elsewhere...
$('#thingy').unbind('keypress', keypressHandler);
```

Comment: Your answer seemed to be a little closer to the proper way to do it, but I couldn't get it to work and danp's worked right away.

Comment: @Matt: Glad it got sorted. Actually, danp's answer is the same as the earlier one by Diodeus, it's just a *lot* more thoroughly described (which counts for a lot!). :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }
```

and its opposite

```
function(e){ return true; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just wrap a condition around `event.preventDefault();` in your current code?

Comment: What do you mean? How would that help re-enable the default action?

Comment: It would bypass "preventdefault()", would it not?

Answer (score 0):

Try to [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) the keypress event from document.

I don't know of any other ways to do it.

HTH