# How to stop the working of preventDefault() function

Tags: javascript, preventdefault

How to stop the `preventDefault()` function and what is opposite function of the `preventDefault()` function. How to enable the links after call of ajax stop function?

Comment: There's no opposite to `preventDefault()`. Simply have a condition when preventing the default.

Comment: check out this http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the opposite of evt.preventDefault();](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651933/what-is-the-opposite-of-evt-preventdefault)

Answer (score 0):

Simple don't use it!

If your link is :

```
<a href="www.google.com" id="myLink">link</a>
```

and your event is:

```
$('#myLink').click(function(){
console.log('no prevent')
//some code
return true:
});
```

after log you go to google...

Answer (score 0):

You are using `preventDefault()` as

```
function(e){ e.preventDefault()};
```

and its opposite

```
function(e){ return true; }
```

Hope it will help you :)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651933/what-is-the-opposite-of-evt-preventdefault/8195990#8195990)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an opposite to `preventDefault()`. The opposite to that would be 'do default' which, of course, is done, by default. You need to run a condition that will decide whether the default is prevented, before preventing it.

```
//Your hypothetical 'do default'
e.preventDefault()
if(condition){
    e.doDefault(); //METHOD DOES NOT EXIST!
}

//How you should do it
if(!condition){
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return false; e.preventDefault();
```

both work same it prevents the process and stop the execution

and about your question there is one option `return true;` to continue the execution of function.

I hope it will help to solve the problem.