# jQuery how to enable a tag after preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have stopped a link / anchor tag trigger event when it clicked by using the `preventDefault()` and in the middle of the jQuery  function, I want to trigger the link by disabling the `preventDefault()`. Below you can see my code block,

```
jQuery(".tcf_add_to_cart a").on('click', function( e ){
e.preventDefault();
if( some condition )
{
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        data : data,
        url : 'url',
        success : function( response ) {
            if ( response == 'true' )
            {
                // ENABLE THE LINK AND TRIGGER LINK ACTION                         
            }
        }
    });
}
});
```

as mentioned above I need to enable the blocked link and what is the best & right wayto do this.

Comment: So you want it to follow the link in the if?

Comment: yes I want to follow the link

Comment: this is a good answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24319183/5112247, the idea is to use window.location = (the original href of the anchor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just set the location based on the event target.

```
if ( response == 'true' ) {
  window.location.href = e.target.href
}
```

You can not cancel the preventDefault since the call is asynchronous.

Comment: instead of `e.target.href` I assigned the value to a varible, `var to_page = $(this).attr('href');` and then used it like `window.location.href = to_page;`

Answer (score 1):

Create a hidden link and when you get to the point where you want it to navigate, use that hidden link with a click event...

```
<a href="http://www.yourLink.com">click me</a><a href="http://www.yourLink.com" id="yourLink">&nbsp;</a>
```

and then in your code add:

```
$("#yourLink").click();
```

to trigger it.

also, you could hide the link like: `$("#yourLink").hide();`

Comment: Yes this does the the job. not a pure JS solution but a good technique to over come the issue.