# Detecting Alt key in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, keyboard-events

In my app I need to handle Alt key press/release to toggle additional information on tooltips. However, the first time Alt is pressed, document loses keyboard focus, because it goes to Chrome's menu. If I click any part of the document, it works again (once).

I can avoid this by calling `preventDefault`, but that also disables keyboard shortcuts such as Alt+Left/Right, which is undesirable.

I can also handle `mousemove` and check `altKey` flag, but it looks very awkward when things only update when mouse is moved.

Is there any way to reliably detect current Alt key state in my situation? I would really rather not switch to a different key.

**Update:** I suppose the best solution would be to call `preventDefault` only when a tooltip is active.

```
  document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    if (this.curComponent) e.preventDefault();
    if (e.which === 18) {
      this.outer.classList.add("AltKey");
    }
  });
  document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
    if (this.curComponent) e.preventDefault();
    if (e.which === 18) {
      this.outer.classList.remove("AltKey");
    }
  });
```

Comment: Did you manage to get this around.  Same problem here

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and I solved thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8195990/1054579):

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Alt") {
        return true; // Instead of e.preventDefault();
    });
```

`return true` restores normal behavior of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> chrome keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I'm using Chrome on Ubuntu 19.04.

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard value both left/ right side ALT = 18

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    if(e.which == 18){
      alert("Alt key press");
    }
});
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.keyup = function(e){
  if(e.which == 18){
    alert("Alt key press");
  }
}
```

Comment: I know how to set the event, but it doesn't work. Please read the question. Also, 17 is Ctrl, not Alt.