# Chrome 'please match the requested format' validation message

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am playing around with HTML 5 validation and localization and have managed to get some code working that allows me to localize the HTML 5 validation error messages (see below).  My problem is, in Chrome when matching against a pattern you still get a pop up in English (or I guess whatever language you have Chrome set up in) 'please match the requested format'.  How do you supress this pop up so that I can just use my own validation messages?

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var elementsInput = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            var elementsTextArea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");

            for (var i = 0; i < elementsInput.length; i++) {
                elementsInput[i].oninvalid = function (e) {
                    e.target.setCustomValidity("");
                    if (!e.target.validity.valid) {

                        switch (e.target.name) {

                            case "Name":
                                if ("@Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name.ToLower()" == "fi-fi") {
                                    e.target.setCustomValidity("Anna nimesi");
                                } else {
                                    e.target.setCustomValidity("Please enter a Name");
                                }
                                break;

                            case "EmailAddress":
                                if (e.target.validity.valueMissing) {
                                    if ("@Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name.ToLower()" == "fi-fi") {
                                        e.target.setCustomValidity("Anna sähköpostiosoitteesi");
                                    } else {
                                        e.target.setCustomValidity("Please enter an Email Address");
                                    }
                                }
                                else if (e.target.validity.patternMismatch) {
                                    if ("@Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name.ToLower()" == "fi-fi") {
                                        e.target.setCustomValidity("Virheellinen sähköpostiosoite");
                                    } else {
                                        e.target.setCustomValidity("Invalid Email Address");
                                    }
                                }
                                break;

                            case "PhoneNumber":
                                if (e.target.validity.valueMissing) {
                                    if ("@Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name.ToLower()" == "fi-fi") {
                                        e.target.setCustomValidity("Anna puhelinnumerosi");
                                    } else {
                                        e.target.setCustomValidity("Please enter a Phone Number");
                                    }
                                }
                                else if (e.target.validity.patternMismatch) {
                                    if ("@Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name.ToLower()" == "fi-fi") {
                                        e.target.setCustomValidity("Virheellinen puhelinnumero");
                                    } else {
                                        e.target.setCustomValidity("Invalid Phone Number");
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                };
                    elementsInput[i].oninput = function (e) {
                        e.target.setCustomValidity("");
                    };
                }

            for (var j = 0; j < elementsTextArea.length; j++) {
                elementsTextArea[j].oninvalid = function (e) {
                    e.target.setCustomValidity("");
                    if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
                        switch (e.target.name) {
                            case "Details":
                                if ("@Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name.ToLower()" == "fi-fi") {
                                    e.target.setCustomValidity("Täytäthän yksityiskohdat");
                                } else {
                                    e.target.setCustomValidity("Please enter Details");
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                };
                elementsTextArea[j].oninput = function (e) {
                    e.target.setCustomValidity("");
                };
            }
        });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 form required attribute. Set custom validation message?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message)

Comment: Not a duplicate of that question

Comment: I hope I was able to answer your question :)

Comment: I'm not sure but you probally have to use e.preventDefault() but can't you check first with e.type if it comes from the popup?

Comment: How would I check that the source is the popup?

Comment: see it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753881/changing-the-language-of-error-message-in-required-field-in-html5-contact-form

Answer (score 6):

The default browser action is to display a popup message. You should use `e.preventDefault();` to prevent it from popping up.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var elementsInput = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var elementsTextArea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");

        for (var i = 0; i < elementsInput.length; i++) {
            elementsInput[i].oninvalid = function (e) {
                e.target.setCustomValidity("");
                if (!e.target.validity.valid) {

                    switch (e.target.name) {

                        case "Name":
                            e.preventDefault();
                            if ("@Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name.ToLower()" == "fi-fi") {
                                e.target.setCustomValidity("Anna nimesi");
                            } else {
                                e.target.setCustomValidity("Please enter a Name");
                            }
                            break;

                        case "EmailAddress":
                            e.preventDefault();
                            if (e.target.validity.valueMissing) {
                                if ("@Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name.ToLower()" == "fi-fi") {
                                    e.target.setCustomValidity("Anna sähköpostiosoitteesi");
                                } else {
                                    e.target.setCustomValidity("Please enter an Email Address");
                                }
                            }
                            else if (e.target.validity.patternMismatch) {
                                if ("@Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name.ToLower()" == "fi-fi") {
                                    e.target.setCustomValidity("Virheellinen sähköpostiosoite");
                                } else {
                                    e.target.setCustomValidity("Invalid Email Address");
                                }
                            }
                            break;

                        case "PhoneNumber":
                            e.preventDefault();
                            if (e.target.validity.valueMissing) {
                                if ("@Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name.ToLower()" == "fi-fi") {
                                    e.target.setCustomValidity("Anna puhelinnumerosi");
                                } else {
                                    e.target.setCustomValidity("Please enter a Phone Number");
                                }
                            }
                            else if (e.target.validity.patternMismatch) {
                                if ("@Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name.ToLower()" == "fi-fi") {
                                    e.target.setCustomValidity("Virheellinen puhelinnumero");
                                } else {
                                    e.target.setCustomValidity("Invalid Phone Number");
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
            };

            elementsInput[i].oninput = function (e) {
                e.target.setCustomValidity("");
            };
        }

        for (var j = 0; j < elementsTextArea.length; j++) {
            elementsTextArea[j].oninvalid = function (e) {
                e.target.setCustomValidity("");
                if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
                    switch (e.target.name) {
                        case "Details":
                            e.preventDefault();
                            if ("@Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name.ToLower()" == "fi-fi") {
                                e.target.setCustomValidity("Täytäthän yksityiskohdat");
                            } else {
                                e.target.setCustomValidity("Please enter Details");
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            };

            elementsTextArea[j].oninput = function (e) {
                e.target.setCustomValidity("");
            };
        }
    });
```

Theoretically you can really put the `e.preventDefault()` right after `if (!e.target.validity.valid) {` but I noticed you didn't have a `default:` in your Switch, so I assumed you didn't want it there. In either case, you can use `e.preventDefault()` inside each individual `case:` where you want it, or you can put it after the `if` statement. Which ever suits your purpose better.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but this prevents all pop ups though, so where I call e.target.setCustomValidity later on in my javascript it gets ignored.

Comment: maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164132/how-to-reenable-event-preventdefault

Comment: what is the jQuery version of this?

Comment: Using e.preventDefault(); on each individual input's onInvalid event shouldn't stop all popups from occurring. The solution is to use e.preventDefault();, however, placement is key... but placement all depends on where and why you want to hide the popup message.

Answer (score 4):

If you're running your own validation you can prevent any built-in HTML5 browser validation by setting the novalidate attribute of the form to "novalidate" like

```
<form name='testForm' method='POST' action='#' novalidate="novalidate">
```

This will tell the browser to prevent applying HTML5 auto-validation.

Comment: this works for me. I was so frustrated and could not find the script or code which was causing the issue. But this piece of code worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery:

```
$('input').on("invalid", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off @michael-angstadt answer. You can automatically add the `novalidate` attribute to your forms by adding this jQuery:

```
$("form").attr('novalidate', 'novalidate');
```