# How to prevent the default browser input validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, input, preventdefault

I have a simple form with phone inputs and some email inputs, however I cannot get rid of the default browser warning messages that come up when I click the submit button.

[image]

[**My CodePen**](http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/HKGiw)

I've tried to implement [event.preventDefault();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056697/chrome-please-match-the-requested-format-validation-message) however it doesn't seem to work in my case.

```
$('#profile-info-form').unbind('submit').bind("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('save button clicked');
});
```

Example of the input fields I create on the fly:

```
var myphone = "<li><label>Cell Phone:</label></li><li><input type='tel' pattern='[0-9]{10}' class='added_mobilephone' name='mobilephone' value='' autocomplete='off' maxlength='20' /></li>";
```

How would you handle this problem?

Comment: Did you try removing the `pattern` attribute? Just using the `tel` type should still get you the keypad interface on mobile.

Comment: Ah whoa I think that was it! Triple checking

Comment: That was it :) do you want to go ahead and post the answer? Thanks again! var mobilephone = $("<li><label>Mobile Phone:</label></li><li><input type='tel' class='added_mobilephone' name='mobilephone' maxlength='20' /></li>");

Comment: Added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `pattern` attribute? Just using the tel type should still get you the keypad interface on mobile and without pattern the native validation/formatting should not run.

Comment: This works in this particular situation, however if there is a regular input for text that is marked as `required` you will receive a warning that it must not be blank.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to disable client side validation for a form add a novalidate attribute to the form element. Fx:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="profile-info-form" novalidate>

 // Your script Here

 </form>
```

See http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-novalidate