# How can I conditionally allow or prevent submission execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

**The situation**

I have a page in which I have multiple forms keeping track of the attendance and one progress_update.

On submit of the progress_update form I have got it so that ajax sends the attendance form submissions separately having used the preventdefault() method to stop the original submission, however I would like to on the condition that no errors were returned by the ajax methods allow the original submission that was originally prevented.

**What I have so far:**

*The ajax function:*

```
    function send_attendance(name, lesson, form_id, i) {
        
        
        var url = '/attendance/' + name + '/' + lesson
       
        $('#error-' + i).hide('slow')
        $('#error-' + i).html('')
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: {
                    attended: $('#attended' + i).val(),
                    score: $('#score' + i).val(),
                    writing: $('#writing' + i).val(),
                    speaking: $('#speaking' + i).val()},
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.data.message == undefined) {
                        allow=false;
                        if (data.data.score[1] == undefined) {
                            var error_data = data.data.score[0]
                        } else {
                            var error_data = data.data.score[1]
                        }
                        $('#error-' + i).show('slow')
                        $('#error-' + i).html('<p  style="color:red;">' + error_data + '</p>')
                    } else {
                        
                        console.log(data.data.message)  // display the returned data in the console.
                    }
                }
            });      
    }
```

The Intention:

The intention behind this ajax is to send the forms to a separate route for validation and then on success "receiving data.data.message == 'submitted'" pass to the next form in the loop, while on error set the allow variable to false and display the message in hopes to prevent the final form being submitted at the same time.

The call:

```
    $('#update_form').submit(function (e) {
            
            var allow = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < studentcount ; i++) {
                send_attendance(name=st[i], lesson=lesson, form_id='attendance-' + i, i=i)
            }
            if (allow == true){
            } else {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

**The Problem**

In doing what I have done I have ended up with a situation of it either submits the ajax submitted forms and that is that preventing the submit form or it submits the form whether errors occured in the ajax that need to be displayed, now how do I get this to work in the way expected? I have tried the methods involved in these previous questions:

[How to reenable event.preventDefault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164132/how-to-reenable-event-preventdefault/1164177#1164177)

[How to unbind a listener that is calling event.preventDefault() (using jQuery)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551389/how-to-unbind-a-listener-that-is-calling-event-preventdefault-using-jquery#1556696)

which revolve around using bind and unbind but this doesn't seem to work as needed and results in a similar error.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

I have adjusted the code based on the comment below to reflect, however it still seems to be evaluating the allow before the ajax have completed. either that or the ajax function isn't changing the allow variable which is set in the submit() call how could i get this to change the allow and evaluate it after the ajax calls are complete?

The Ajax call

```
    function send_attendance(name, lesson, form_id, i) {
        
        var url = '/attendance/' + name + '/' + lesson
        $('#error-' + i).hide('slow')
        $('#error-' + i).html('')
        var form = $('#' + form_id)
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $('#'+ form_id).serialize(),
            context: form,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('done')
                if (data.data.message == undefined) {
                    allow = false;
                    if (data.data.score[1] == undefined) {
                        var error_data = data.data.score[0]
                    } else {
                        var error_data = data.data.score[1]
                            
                    }
                    $('#error-' + i).show('slow')
                    $('#error-' + i).html('<p  style="color:red;">' + error_data + '</p>')
                } else {
                        
                    console.log(data.data.message)  // display the returned data in the console.
                }
            }
        });
```

The function is being called here:

```
    $('#update_form').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var allow = true;

            var deferreds = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < studentcount ; i++) {
                deferreds.push(
                    send_attendance(st[i], lesson, 'attendance-' + i, i));
            }

            $.when(...deferreds).then(function() {
                if (allow == true){
                    console.log('True')
                } else {
                    console.log('False')
                }
            });
```

I also tried:

```
    $('#update_form').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var allow = true;

            var deferreds = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < studentcount ; i++) {
                deferreds.push(
                    send_attendance(st[i], lesson, 'attendance-' + i, i));
            }

            $.when.apply(deferreds).done(function() {
                if (allow == true){
                    console.log('True')
                } else {
                    console.log('False')
                }
            });
```

Comment: Problem you have is multiple asynchronous requests. So you are looking at https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/ and resubmitting the form

Comment: Sorry I dont quite get what you mean

Comment: The ajax calls return as success but I find am hoping that once the for loop has gone though the motion that then it will check the value of allow and if it is true allow submittion

Comment: Read the documentation for when.... I do not have time to make an answer

Comment: I have looked through however the thing is the ajax isn't returning failure at all it is returning either a object with a message or and object with the form errors hence why I am unsure of how this would be the solution, as the from the documentation 'Execute the function myFunc when both ajax requests are successful, or myFailure if either one has an error.' however the ajax functions are returnig however the allow variable isn't being changed and I am unsure as to why as I am hoping with this changing from true to false conditionally that it can then be used to either prevent or not

Comment: another question would be why isnt allow changing from true to false in the submit() function but is in the send_attendance() function? why isnt the send_attendance changint the submit() allow variable

Comment: Because Ajax is asynchronous

Comment: I took your advice with the when() call however still doesn't seem to function correctly I have added the edits I have done to the post above

Comment: Are you returning the Ajax call? `return $.ajax({ type: "POST",`....`